# Laravel cronjob not running on the server

Tags: php, laravel-4, cron

I wanted to ask how automation of tasks aka cronjobs on a website are run using laravel commands?

I created a command following the tutsplus tutorial and call my functions in the fire method below:

```
public function fire()
{
    $feeds= new FeedsController;
    $update='update';
    $feeds->getUpdateYoutube($update);
    $feeds->getUpdateInstagram($update);
    $feeds->getUpdateTwitter($update);
    $feeds->getUpdateFacebook($update);
    $feeds->getWriteToFile();
    $this->info('Success');
}
```

However, this does not get called at all, despite the fact I included it called it on the server like so: 0 */2 *   *   *   php /home/path/public_html/website artisan feeds-refresh

any clues what I am doing wrong?

Comment: If you type `php artisan feeds-refresh` in your console - does the command work by itself? If so, the problem is with your cron not calling the job correctly. If it does not work in the console, then the problem is with your code.

Comment: It does run from the console, but not when called on the server

Comment: So are you sure it is even 'firing' from the server? Check your server logs